# How to write to next line of CSV if data exists (from loop) C#

Tags: c#, api, loops, csv

I have a loop, which writes the values of an array to a .csv file.  It works, but it writes all the data to the same lines each loop.  How can I make it to where it moves down to the next line of empty space after each loop?  I believe it is doing this, because I have the same content also being written to a text box, and all the data is there, but when I look at the .csv file, only the last items of the array shows up.

I am new to C#, and I am sure there is a better way to write out the string, but I will learn that later on, my main focus is on writing the data values into the .csv file:

I'm only providing this small amount of code because I believe it is where the issue is coming from.  If needed, I can copy in the loop or something else.

```
string pathCleansed = @"C:\dev\data\cleansed.csv";
                string[] createText = { 
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].StreetAddress1,
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].StreetAddress2,
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].SubDivision,
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].City,
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].PostalCode,
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].MainDivision,
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].confidenceIndicator
                    };
                File.WriteAllLines(pathCleansed, createText, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: If you want to APPEND to the end of the file with your new "set" of lines, then use [AppendAllLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=netcore-3.1) instead.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: [`File.WriteAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_WriteAllLines_System_String_System_String___System_Text_Encoding_) overwrite the file content with the new one. Take a look at [`File.AppendAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=netcore-3.1). To add a break line use `Environment.NewLine`. That said, if you do this inside a loop these methods open and close the file on each call, better use `FileStream` class.